# How can I read from a HttpWebRequest/WebResponse to a file without using a byte buffer?

Tags: c#, .net, memory-management, httpwebrequest, filestream

I'm currently using a `HttpWebRequest`/`WebResponse` to read to a byte array of length determined based on the available memory and number of simultaneous downloads then using a `FileStream` to write it to a file.
Given that even when a large array falls out of scope it is not cleaned from memory - potentially for quite a long time, I would like to divert the data straight into the `FileStream` to remove the need for the byte array entirely.
Of course, the other option is to manually call `GC.Collect()` but as I'm sure people will agree that isn't the best of ideas.

My code for reference:

```
    private void Worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        BackgroundWorker bW = sender as BackgroundWorker;
        Req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(FileSource);
        Req.AddRange(BRead, ByteTotal); //This is why I'm using httpwebrequest
        using (WebResponse resp = Req.GetResponse())
        using (Stream respStream = resp.GetResponseStream())
        {
            RunDL(bW, resp, respStream, e);
        }
    }

    private void RunDL(BackgroundWorker bW, WebResponse resp, Stream respStream, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        byte[] Buffer = new byte[ChunkSize];
        CurChunkSpace = 0;
        while (BRead < ByteTotal)
        {
            if (bW.CancellationPending)
            {
                e.Cancel = true;
                break;
            }
            int temp = CurChunkSpace;
            if (BRead + (Buffer.Length - CurChunkSpace) > ByteTotal)
            {
                CurChunkSpace += respStream.Read(Buffer, CurChunkSpace, ByteTotal - BRead);
            }
            else
            {
                CurChunkSpace += respStream.Read(Buffer, CurChunkSpace, Buffer.Length - CurChunkSpace);
            }
            temp = CurChunkSpace - temp;
            BRead += temp;
            bW.ReportProgress(BRead);
            if (bW.CancellationPending)
            {
                if (KeepFile)
                {
                    using (FileStream FS = new FileStream(FilePath, FileMode.Append))
                    {
                        FS.Write(Buffer, 0, BRead - BWritten);
                        BWritten = BRead;
                    }
                }
                e.Cancel = true;
                break;
            }
            if (CurChunkSpace == Buffer.Length)
            {
                using (FileStream FS = new FileStream(FilePath, FileMode.Append))
                {
                    FS.Write(Buffer, 0, Buffer.Length);
                    BWritten += Buffer.Length;
                    CurChunkSpace = 0;
                }
                if (ChunkChangePending)
                {
                    ChunkChangePending = false;
                    Buffer = new byte[ChunkSize];
                }
            }
        }
        if(BWritten != BRead)
        {
            using (FileStream FS = new FileStream(FilePath, FileMode.Append))
            {
                if (TotalChunks == 1)
                {
                    FS.Write(Buffer, BWritten, Buffer.Length);
                    BWritten += Buffer.Length - BWritten;
                } else
                {
                    FS.Write(Buffer, 0, CurChunkSpace);
                    BWritten += CurChunkSpace;
                }
            }
        }
        Array.Clear(Buffer, 0, Buffer.Length);
    }
```

Also, would it be more efficient for me to include the `FileStream` in the earlier `using` statements (in `Worker_DoWork()`)?

Comment: You mean *write* to a file. You can copy all data from one stream to another with `Stream.CopyTo`. Your code would be a lot shorter and cleaner if you didn't use the obsolete BackgroundWorker though. Task-based methods like CopyToAsync support cancellation. [HttpClient.GetStreamAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh551739(v=vs.118).aspx) can make an asynchronous call *and* return a stream in a single line

Comment: The issue with using `Stream.CopyTo` and it's async counterpart is that I need to be able to report progress.

Comment: How big is your buffer? You can make that buffer, say, 512kb which will be reused on every subsequent read of the stream. The entire file won't be loaded into memory just 512kb at a time which eliminates the concern of large amount of memory not being garbage collected in a timely fashion.

Comment: @TheHitchenator reporting progress is easy. Just read chunks into  a single buffer with Read/ReadAsync and copy it to the target stream. That' adds perhaps 2-3 lines. Use the built-in `IProgress< T>` interface to report progress.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos yes, that's why I'm not using the `Stream.CopyTo` method - I'm using `Stream.Read` and `stream.write`. I already have progress reporting done which is why I wasn't asking about it. I also see no evidence of BackgroundWorker being obsolete, could you clarify what leads you to that conclusion?

Comment: @mnemonic I am using a buffer of size determined by the amount of available memory due to the large potential number of files being downloaded at once. Because the files can often be larger than 9gb I would prefer not to throttle it to 512kb at a time where not necessary (it takes longer to write to files in many small chunks than in fewer large chunks due to the way hard drives work)